# Does IE10 use JScript 10.0

Tags: javascript, javascript-engine, jscript-10, internet-explorer-10

```
@if (@_jscript_version == 10)
    document.write("You are using IE10");
```

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Conditional_Comment_in_JScript) IE10 will use JScript 10.

[JScript 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h4yzx6.aspx) seems to have a whole bunch of new proprietary extensions to EcmaScript 5.

**Is the version of the EcmaScript engine (10) in IE10 related to JScript 10.0 ?**

**Does IE10 bring in a whole load of proprietary extensions like strict typing, etc?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears I was mistaken, and JScript 10.0 and JScript (in IE) with a version of 10 are entirely unrelated, and Microsoft's versioning schemes are abhorrent.

Comment: more specific  - he's asking about version, not just that jscript relates to ecmascript

Comment: See the second question. JScript 10.0 is a _very different_ language from JScript 9.0 and ES5. JScript 10.0 seems to build on JScript 7/8/.NET

Comment: That second question wasn't there when I answered.

Comment: @d_r_w so in IE10 I can have static types, and in IE9 I cannot? I've also taken a quote from microsoft stating JScript 10.0 is unrelated to web browsers, is that quote false?

Comment: @Raynos Nope, you cannot have static types in IE10. IE10 just supports regular Javascript. You can have static types, access to .NET, etc., only if you compile JScript code with `jsc` (but then you'll get an `exe`/`dll` which can't be run in a web browser). I'm not sure but it seems that both Javascript in IE10 and JScript.NET are called "Jscript 10.0".

Comment: +1 for versioning schemes are abhorrent. @duri that's really annoying,

Answer (score 5):

[Microsoft Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkx7dfw1.aspx)

> JScript 10.0 is used for applications that run on a server by using the .NET Framework. For information about how to write scripts that run on a client computer in a Web browser, see JScript (Windows Script Technologies).

It would appear they are just being annoying with version numbers. The JScript 10.0 seems to run on the .NET framework only.

Although I still don't know what "Jscript version 10" is and why it has the same version number as JScript 10.0